# setting the topic when using the pyobj subfunctions in zeromq/python

Tags: python, zeromq

I have been looking at zeromq and i noticed there were socket.send_pyobj() and socket.recv_pyobj() functions.

My question is how would one set the topic for PUB/SUB if they called this. In the examples i have seen that have used the regular send it was always two strings with a space in between and first string would be considered a topic.

```
topic = 'test'
msg = 'hello'
socket.send("%s %s" % (topic,msg))
```

Is there a way? Or maybe should i use different ports as a way to make different topics?

Answer (score 9):

NVM. figured out how to do it. I should use send_multipart if i want the topic and msg viewed as one and also filter the object.

For the publisher.

```
   self.socket.send_multipart([b'status',pickle.dumps(msg2)])
```

For the reciver.

```
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'status')
    [topic,msg] = socket.recv_multipart()
    msg2 = pickle.loads(msg)
    print msg2['game']
```

I don't know why but if you use their example. [http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:psenvsub](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3apsenvsub) it shows i should do b'status' on the socketopt but it didnt filter if i did it that wya.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that others will know your problem is solved.