# How to add topic filters when calling recv_pyobj() in ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

ZeroMQ provides pretty good documentation about how to set up a [pub-sub pattern](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html) with the topic filter, as described in [the api docs](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-setsockopt). ZeroMQ also provides the methods `socket.send_json()` and `socket.send_pyobj()` (and the `recv` counterparts) for [convenience](https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.send_pyobj).

In the pub-sub example, the topic filter (a string) is appended to the beginning of the message (also a string). Is there any way to set up a topic filter when using the built-in serialization? If I am sending a `dict` or `Class` using `send_pyobj()` I cannot append a string in front of it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First thing to note is that ZeroMQ does not provide `send_json()` or `send_pyobj()` as convenience methods, these are provided by the pyzmq binding. So, ZMQ does not know anything about those data types - basically what's happening is that those methods just perform the serialization and unserialization of the the data under the hood.

Like you, I haven't seen a single example of pub/sub working with these convenience methods that didn't just subscribe to `''`.  But, it *should* be possible, if a bit of a hack to do so.

As you can [see here in the source](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/4652a17904bb77db87be13f53c30a7af9213f9ef/zmq/sugar/socket.py#L407), `send_pyobj()` uses `pickle` to serialize the data. You can use that fact to see what your data looks like once it's serialized. You can add an extra element to your `dict` or `Class`, provided you can be certain it goes *first* in the serialized string, and then look at the serialization and just use the beginning of the string as your subscribe topic.  If you *can't* be certain your topic element will come first, then you'll have to create an envelope of some kind that you have a bit more control over, and send that with your data inside it and just dereference it when you receive it.

Hacky, ugly, and ultimately probably a bad idea, [even according to the writers of the pyzmq binding themselves](https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/serialization.html) - relevant quote (emphasis added):

> we do provide three builtin serialization methods for convenience, **to help Python developers learn libzmq**... These methods designed for convenience, not for performance, so developers who do want to emphasize performance should use their own serialized send/recv methods.

It's probably far better to just serialize the data yourself and send a proper multiframe message with your topic in the first frame.  You can find an example of such [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048319/setting-the-topic-when-using-the-pyobj-subfunctions-in-zeromq-python).

```
// publisher
self.socket.send_multipart([b'status',pickle.dumps(msg2)])

// subscriber
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'status')
[topic,msg] = socket.recv_multipart()
msg2 = pickle.loads(msg)
print msg2['game']
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only method working for serializing.